# How can all keys and values of an array and make them in there own array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Let say my array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] = Charcoal,Natural Gas,Combo
    [1] = Charcoal,Propane,Combo
    [2] = Charcoal,Propane,Natural Gas,Combo
    [3] = Natural Gas
)
```

What could I do to make it look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] = Charcoal,Natural Gas,Combo
)
Array
(
    [0] = Charcoal,Propane,Combo
)
Array
(
    [0] = Charcoal,Propane,Natural Gas,Combo
)
Array
(
    [0] = Natural Gas
)
```

Comment: `$newArray = array(); foreach($oldArray as $value) {$newArray[][] = $value; } var_dump($newArray);`

Answer (score 0):

At first glance i would suggest this:

```
$array = Array
(
    [0] = Charcoal,Natural Gas,Combo
    [1] = Charcoal,Propane,Combo
    [2] = Charcoal,Propane,Natural Gas,Combo
    [3] = Natural Gas
);
$array2 = array();
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $array2[][] = $item;
}
```

On second thought instead of showing a new array of how you want it to look like, you show me multiple arrays. That would mean an implementation like this:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    print_r($item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   ## hope this helps ##

  <?php
$array = Array('Charcoal, Natural 
Gas,Combo','Charcoal,Propane,Combo','Charcoal,Propane,Natural Gas,Combo', 'Natural 
Gas');

$d1 = array_slice($array, 0, 1);
$d2 = array_slice($array, 1, 1);
$d3= array_slice($array, 2, 1);
$d4 = array_slice($array, 3, 1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($d1);
print_r($d2);
print_r($d3);
print_r($d4);
echo "</pre>";


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) function.

```
$array = array('Charcoal, Natural gas, Combo' ,'Charcoal,Propane,Combo', 'Charcoal,Propane,Natural Gas, Combo', 'Natural Gas' );

$arr = array_chunk($array,1);
```

See [demo](https://eval.in/135901)